# Facebook PHP SDK - Graph API Like

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Can someone help me with this, if you go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and use Graph API, GET Method on Connections->Home - You can grab your news feed.

In that newsfeed, the array shows some information based on each individual feed item.

One thing on there is `likes` which has a sub value of `count` which counts the number of likes.

Problem is, when I change it to use my applications and access token, the information is still there, expect the `count` part.

This is really confusing, I have read_stream as a scope.

My code the fetch the likes is:

```
if(isset($news['likes']['count'])) $likes_count = $news['likes']['count'];
else $likes_count = 0;
```

Which is part of my foreach loop.

For good measure, here is the function:

```
function newsitem($profile_pic,$from,$to,$message,$picture,$name,$link,$caption,$description,$icon,$time,$comments,$likes)
            {
                if($to) $to_section = '<div class="to" >to</div><div class="news-friend-name"><strong><a>' . $to . '</a></strong></div><div class="clear"></div>';
                else $to_section = '';

                if($message) $message_section = '<div class="message">' . $message . '</div>';
                else $message_section = '';

                if($picture) $picture_section = '<div class="external-image"><img src="' . $picture . '"/></div><div class="news-external">';
                else $picture_section = '<div class="news-external" style="width: 410px;">';

                if(!$link) $link='#';

                if($name) $name_section = '<div class="news-title"><h3><a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $name . '</a></h3></div>';
                else $name_section = '';

                if($caption) $caption_section = '<div class="news-caption"><i>' . $caption . '</i></div>';
                else $caption_section = '';

                if($description) $description_section = '<div class="news-desc">' . $description . '</div>';
                else $description_section = '';

                if($icon) $icon_section = '<div class="news-icon" ><img src="' . $icon . '" /></div>';
                else $icon_section = '';

                $time_converted = time_elapsed($time);

                $news = '<div class="news">
                                <div class="news-friend-thumb"><img src="' . $profile_pic . '"/></div>
                                <div class="news-content">
                                    <div class="news-friend-name"><strong><a>'. $from . '</a></strong></div>'.$to_section.                          
                                    '<div class="clear"></div>' . $message_section . $picture_section . $name_section . $caption_section . $description_section .
                                    '</div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                    <div class="comment-like">' . $icon_section . $time_converted . ' ago  &bull;  ' . $comments . ' comments  &bull;  ' . $likes . ' likes</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                    return $news;
            }`
```

I'd appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: you may try like this : if(isset($news['data']['likes']['count'])) $likes_count = $news['data']['likes']['count'];
else $likes_count = 0;

Comment: I tried that, and just tried it from your comment to make sure I didn't miss anything out, but it is still returning nothing, after I use var_dump($likes_count) it returns 'int(0)', and print_r($likes_count) returns '0'.

Thanks for trying to help though! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You must be mistaken. I only see `count` for shares. There is no count for `likes` except for comments, which has `like_count`.